# Wordpress Deleting a custom DB row

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm working on a custom plugin for myself to add and delete custom links. I got the adding working, but deleting it is giving me a headache.

This is my adding code:

```
$naam=$_POST["naam"];
$link=$_POST["link"];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxx");
if(!$con) {
die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}
?>
<?php
$sql="INSERT INTO `xxx`.`wp_backlinks` ( `naam` , `link` ) VALUES ( '$naam','$link')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Now I need a script to delete it. My intention is that I can delete the row out of the database with a link.

So,

```
[ Custom Link] [ Delete Link ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WordPress WPDB class to accomplish database access tasks:

```
global $wbpd;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . "wp_backlinks"; // OR $table = $wpdb->prefix . "backlinks";
//$wpdb->prefix = "wp_" by default
$where = "put your condition here";
$wpdb->delete( $table, $where);
```

Follow the link [DELETE Rows](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#DELETE_Rows) for more details.

In general you should also use it for insert data as database details like host, username, password, db-prefix may be changed from WP Configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! 
I looked into the WPDB, but i couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Like this ? 

'$wpdb->insert("wp_backlinks", array(
   "naam" => $naam;
   "link" => $link;
));'

Comment: $wpdb->insert("wp_backlinks", array( "naam" => $naam; "link" => $link; )); is correct; you can use db prefix also as I mentioned.